# search exact value of cell in a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a description in Column A which contains some error code like ESFB-1 , ESFB-11 etc... with list of error codes in sheet2 a total of about 36 error codes

I have the below code written & works but the only problem is it is treating both ESFB-1 & ESFB-11 as same the list has about 35 error codes with similar nomenclature below is the code

```
enter code here
Sub sear()
Dim rng As Range
Dim str As String
Dim str1 As String
Dim val1 As Long
Dim val2 As Long
Dim col As Integer
Dim col2 As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim var As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim pos As Integer
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
var = 0
col = 1
row = 2
row2 = 2
pos = 0
Do While var <> 1
   Do While row <= lastrow1
       Do While pos = 0
           str = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 1).Value
           str1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row2, 1).Value
           pos = InStrRev(str, str1, vbTextCompare)
           row2 = row2 + 1
           If row2 = lastRow Then Exit Do
        Loop
        If pos <> 0 Then
        Cells(row, 7).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row2 - 1, 1)
        End If
        Cells(row, 8).Value = pos & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 1)
        pos = 0
        row2 = 2
        row = row + 1
    Loop
var = 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Please suggest modifications which can help me find the exact error code from description

Comment: If your error message is normally followed by a space, add those in your list of error messages, so that "ESFB-1 " does not match "ESFB-11"

Comment: Regex? That way you can use $ to say the string must end here.

Comment: it may or may not end with space.

Comment: Why `InStrRev`?

Comment: Desc could be anything like below

User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-1- caller is needing a Skype account
 or
User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-11- caller is needing a Skype account
or
User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-1 - caller is needing a Skype account
or
User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-11 - caller is needing a Skype account

Comment: I tried both Instr also the result was same so tried with InstrRev

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve. I have a feeling that there is a much better way to achieve what you want

Comment: Would `if str=str1 then ` not do it?

Comment: There is a summary column in a report which contains a summary like belowDesc could be anything like below

User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-1- caller is needing a Skype account
 or
User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-11- caller is needing a Skype account
or
User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-1 - caller is needing a Skype account
or
User is not a Pilot or Beta user : ESFB-11 - caller is needing a Skype account

In another sheet I have all the Errorcodes listed

I need to write a macro so that I can extract the error code from summary column

Comment: Sorry but I am confused :D Can you upload your workbook to a free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g8a86f6aef5343acd999966942e98596ac0daf914e

Comment: Does your `pos = InStrRev(str, str1,  vbTextCompare)` always return 0?

Comment: No I get the correct pos the only problem is it is stops the search once it is find ing ESFB-1 through the correct error code in string is ESFB-11

Comment: @Luuklag Correct. I just checked all of your errors with =MID(A1,SEARCH("ESFB-1",A1),7)... all of your errors have a space after them

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instr` will give you false positive like you are getting for `ESFB-1` & `ESFB-11` and hence you need a more robust check.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Arws As Variant, tempAr As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
    
    '~~> Set your sheets here
    Set ws1 = Sheet1: Set ws2 = Sheet2
    
    With ws2
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        
        '~~> Store the error codes in an array
        Arws = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    End With
    
    With ws1
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        
        '~~> This is your range from 1st sheet
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lRow)
        
        '~~> Loop through all cells and split it's contents
        For Each aCell In rng
            tempAr = Split(aCell.Value)
            '~~> Loop through each split word in the array
            For i = LBound(tempAr) To UBound(tempAr)
                '~~> Check if exists in array
                If ExistsInArray(Trim(tempAr(i)), Arws) Then
                    '~~> If it does then write to col B
                    aCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Trim(tempAr(i))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Next aCell
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if a string is int he array
Function ExistsInArray(s As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim bDimen As Byte, i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(UBound(arr, 2)) Then bDimen = 1 Else bDimen = 2
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case bDimen
    Case 1
        On Error Resume Next
        ExistsInArray = Application.Match(s, arr, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Case 2
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
            ExistsInArray = Application.Match(s, Application.Index(arr, , i), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ExistsInArray = True Then Exit For
        Next
    End Select
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy that's what I was trying to do.. I am basically not from programming background just tried to apply what I leart during my studies...

Comment: no worries :) Just do not copy and paste the code. Understand how it works ;)

Comment: Doing that only... as I have to combine it with another code on my main workbook. This one was just a sample with one col in actual work book the summary col is not the first col & error code is in other file

Comment: Just noticed that some error codes are shown blank though it has values in it. Please help in checking it...